# Need to pass value of p:inputText to a bean when p:commandButton is pressed

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF-2.0 dialog which has three p:inputText fields who's contents I want to make accessible to a bean when the p:commandButton is pressed.  I have tried using f:attribute but that either passes the exact text of what I place into 'value' OR I get null if I try something like:

```
<h:form id="form">  
            <p:dataTable var="config" value="#{configBean.configList}" selection="#{configBean.selectedConfigs}">
                <p:column selectionMode="multiple">               
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                            Delete?  
                    </f:facet>                      
                </p:column> 



            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{config.name}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Key">
                <h:outputText value="#{config.key}" />  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="Value">
                <h:outputText value="#{config.value}" />  
            </p:column>  
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton value="Add Row" 
                         oncomplete="addRowDialog.show()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Delete" 
                         action="#{configBean.deleteSelectedConfigs}"/>

        <p:dialog header="Add Row" widgetVar="addRowDialog"  id="dialog"
                  width="250" height="300" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

            <h:outputLabel for="name2" value="Name:"/>
            <p:inputText id="name2" name="name2" required="true"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{configBean.addNewConfigProperty}" onclick="addRowDialog.hide()" update="config">              
            <f:attribute name="name1" value="#{requestScope.name2}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:dialog>                              
    </h:form>
```

is it possible to pass the value of what is found in the inputText this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `value` attribute of `p:inputText` to bind it's content to a backing bean value:

```
<p:inputText id="name2" value="#{myBean.myTextField}" required="true"/>
```

And in your bean:

```
String myTextField;
// add getter and setter
```

If you want to bind the inputText to a different datatype you need a [converter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnast.html).

Comment: That was the first method I tried but the value kept being lost between views of the page, even with @ViewScoped set which is why I am trying to use attributes, thus when the button is clicked all of the data is present in the ActionEvent.

Comment: @Ryland: If you switch to a different view, the @ViewScoped bean is destroyed and your value gets lost (which is expected behavior). If you want to keep the value you either have to use @SessionScoped or prefill your ViewScoped bean with the values stored in your database (if this is what you are doing).

Comment: The page shows a table with an "Add Row" commandButton which then launches a p:dialog in which they enter information.  The p:dialog has a button "Submit" which then calls a backing method on the bean.  If I do "value=" and put a breakpoint in the individual setters it gets hit but the data is not being stored between each of the "set" calls that is made (goes back to null).  That is why I switched to trying to use attributes.